# how to debug nodeunit using node-inspector

Tags: node.js, nodeunit, node-inspector

I can do:

- I can test node.js modules using [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit).
- I can debug my node.js express site using [node inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector).

But how to debug nodeunit test using node inspector?

I tried, but not working:

- `nodeunit --debug myNodeUnitModule_test.js` It's not working.
- I tried to install [nodebug](https://npmjs.org/package/nodebug).
  And used it like this: `nodebug /usr/local/bin/nodeunit myNodeunit_test.js` But it's not working neither on ubuntu (`No such file or directory`) nor on mac (`env: node\r: No such file or directory`)

**Almost works**
[node --debug /usr/local/bin/nodeunit ./routes/edit/bodyTelInfoArraysToObject_test.js](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/by_WQ5G3Ycc)

where `/usr/local/bin/nodeunit` is path taken by command `which nodeunit`

got output: 
`debugger listening on port 5858`
and test executed there.

But I can't jump in debuggin: when I open url `localhost:8080` in chrome to watch debugging:

2. first load I see empty file list
3. second load: page not found.

On my nodeunit test I wrote `debugger` to stop on debug there.
But nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your tests insert `debugger;` command

```
exports['Main test'] = function(test){
    debugger;

    test.expect(1);
    test.ok(true, 'Must be ok');
    test.done();
};
```

And start all this

```
$ node --debug-brk `which nodeunit` test.js
```

Now in browser press F8, then F10, and you are right on the next line after first `debugger;` command in your test.

But I prefer to start everything with node-supervisor, that restart test automatically when test finished or files in project directory changed:

```
$ npm -g install supervisor node-inspector

$ # console 1
$ # supervisor restarts node-inspector when it quits
$ # ignores file changes
$ supervisor -i . -x node-inspector .

$ # console 2
$ supervisor --debug-brk -- `which nodeunit` test/index.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution found:

- in console:
  **node --debug-brk `which nodeunit` ./path/To/My/NodeUnitTests/nodeunit_test.coffee** (Attention: `which nodeunit` is in back quotes)
- in another console: 
  `node-inspector &`
- And in google chrome open: `http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858`
  Here I see nodeunit debuging from the start. Click continue execution several times in browser until  jump to nodeunit test, where I have `debugger;` string. So I debugging my nodeunit test with nodeinspector